# How to get various runtime statistics of another app : RAM, Heap, CPU,...?

Tags: android, root, cpu-usage, heap-memory, ram

### Background

I'm interested in showing various real-time statistics about a chosen app (an app the user can choose), such as RAM, Heap memory, CPU,...

### The problem

Over Android versions, it has become harder to get some statistics. This includes even getting the processes of an app.

### What I've found

For Heap:

I know that using root (or a connected PC), I could get the heap stats of another app, by using **dumpsys meminfo** command, but I wonder if there is already an API for this.

For network:

I know this is possible, using some permissions:

```
        long[] rxAndTx = new long[2];
        applicationInfo = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
        final int uid = applicationInfo.uid;
        NetworkStatsManager networkStatsManager = VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.M ? context.getSystemService(NetworkStatsManager.class) : null;
        final String subscriberId = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getSubscriberId();
        getNetworkUsage(networkStatsManager, subscriberId, uid, rxAndTx);
```

Getting a list of processes is possible by using the "ps" command, but it will show a full list (including of other apps) only if you are calling it with root privilege (meaning call "su" before).

### The question

Is there an API for getting the CPU, the RAM, and the heap memory of a chosen app?

I prefer official API, but if there isn't root is also ok.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux

Comment: @pskink The path "/proc" will show other processes only if you call it with root privilege. Is there any other way?

Comment: `I prefer official API, but if there isn't root is also ok.`

Comment: @pskink Yes, but what exactly do you offer to use there? How do I get which of them are of apps? And after that, how do I get any kind of the information I wrote about?

Comment: @pskink I think I can know which processes belong to which apps, by looking at the "cmdline" file. However, I think you need to parse each APK of the installed apps, to know exactly which process/es belong to which apps. Maybe the "ps" command can also help.

Comment: @pskink In fact, "dumpsys meminfo" shows a list of processes for the chosen app, so it can help. Still, I don't get how and what you can find from the "/proc" folder. Can you please show what you mean? Maybe some examples?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: @pskink On which of them to look at? Maybe for RAM, I should look at "stat" file, on the "rss" or "vsize" values? Or maybe I should look at "statm" file ? Where can I get the max heap size of the app? Please help. Providing a link of so much information can't help much

Comment: most likely `/proc/[pid]/limits`, `/proc/[pid]/stat` and `/proc/[pid]/statm`

Comment: @pskink Which of their info should I read for which of what I've written (ram, cpu, heap,...) ?

Comment: see [top](https://www.lifewire.com/linux-top-command-2201163) command, it shows many useful info from `/proc` filesystem, the sources are pretty short (200-300kB) so you will find out easily how it reads `/proc`

Comment: @pskink There are multiple types of RAM. Which to look at?

Comment: stat[vsize], stat[rss], statm[size], statm[resident], statm[share], statm[text], statm[lib], statm[data], statm[dt], it all depends what you want

Comment: @pskink I want to know which of the to use, for total RAM usage of the app. Also CPU usage could be nice

Comment: so what [top](https://www.lifewire.com/linux-top-command-2201163) command source files did you see?

Comment: @pskink Should I look as "vss" or "rss" ? How do I know which process belongs to which app? The only thing I notice here is that such processes probably have "user" field set as something like "u#_*" , where # is a number, and * is anything else. As I remember, a process name is usually the same as the package name, but I also remember it doesn't have to be this way, as apps can have more than one process (yet I think it's just ":" after the package name and then the customized name).

Comment: RunningAppProcessInfo

Comment: @pskink This is official API, which returns almost empty list (returns only processes of the current app) starting from certain Android version (I think 5.1.1 ) .